# error converting % to datatype int in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

iam using simple query i want year to get extracted and that should be used in table extraction

```
select * 
from  v_AuthListInfo LI 
where title like '%SUG%' 
  and Title like '%P1%' 
  and Title like '%' + '' + year(getdate()) +  '' + '%'
```

I am getting this error

> ```
> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.
> ```

Ideally it should come 2018 and it should extract those records with 2018
and I want records minus 1 yr means 2017
so in all I want records of 2018 and 2017

but iam not able to get can you tell me where iam going wrong in concatenation

want to combine output of these two queries

```
    select
count(*) [Total Clients], li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,
SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1  then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Installed / Not Applicable',
sum( case When ucs.status=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Required',
sum( case When ucs.status=0 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unknown',
round((CAST(SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float)/count(*) )*100,2) as 'Compliant%',
    round((CAST(count(case when ucs.status not in('3','1') THEN '*' end) as float)/count(*))*100,2) as 'NotCompliant%'
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatusAll UCS
inner join v_r_system sys on ucs.resourceid=sys.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on ucs.resourceid=fcm.resourceid
inner join v_collection coll on coll.collectionid=fcm.collectionid
inner join v_AuthListInfo LI on ucs.ci_id=li.ci_id
where coll.CollectionID='SMS00001' and
--title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' 
and Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar) +  '' + '%'
--and Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name
order by li.title ASC


select
count(*) [Total Clients], li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,
SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1  then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Installed / Not Applicable',
sum( case When ucs.status=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Required',
sum( case When ucs.status=0 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unknown',
round((CAST(SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float)/count(*) )*100,2) as 'Compliant%',
    round((CAST(count(case when ucs.status not in('3','1') THEN '*' end) as float)/count(*))*100,2) as 'NotCompliant%'
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatusAll UCS
inner join v_r_system sys on ucs.resourceid=sys.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on ucs.resourceid=fcm.resourceid
inner join v_collection coll on coll.collectionid=fcm.collectionid
inner join v_AuthListInfo LI on ucs.ci_id=li.ci_id
where coll.CollectionID='SMS00001' and
--title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' 
-- Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar) +  '' + '%'
and Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name
order by li.title ASC
```

Comment: can you please provide the datatype of title column.

Comment: If you have to search the *title* for a year, something's very wrong with your view. You are forcing the database to scan **all** records in the table where `Title` comes from to find matches. No indexes can be used to speed this up since you are searching in the middle of the value. Either add a separate, indexed `Year` column or create and use a full text search index

Comment: Using `CONCAT()` gets around most of these problems by implicitly converting all parameters to strings.

Answer (score 4):

Cast your `year` to `varchar` because year returns `int` value

```
select * from  v_AuthListInfo LI 
where title like '%SUG%' 
and Title like '%P1%' 
and Title like '%' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) +  '' + '%'
```

Comment: when iam using -1 its not giving me rows like  Title like '%P1%' 
and Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar) +  '' + '%'
--and Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%' i deally it should give rows with 2018 and 2017 but its not showing any data wondering why if used separately it shows proper data but when used together its showing no rows

Comment: `Title like '%P1%' and 
Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate()) as varchar) + '' + '%' 
OR Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) + '' + '%'` Use `OR` not and because both case can't satisfied for a row

Comment: @HABO actually is one character if it is a parameter. In a query like that it is 30. Another reason why length should always be specified. Nothing like default sizes changing based on context. :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `year()` returns a number, not a string.  Because of this, SQL Server interprets the `+` as addition, rather than string concatenation.

SQL Server has a convenient function, [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql), that returns a string:

```
select *
from  v_AuthListInfo LI 
where title like '%SUG%' and
      title like '%P1%' and
      title like '%' + datename(year, getdate()) + '%';
```

The empty strings that you are concatenating in the `like` pattern are useless.

Comment: iam getting only 2018 records with this condition where coll.CollectionID='SMS00001' and
--title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' 
and      title like '%SUG_' + datename(year, getdate()) + '%'
and title like '%SUG_' + datename(year, getdate()+1) + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name
order by li.title ASC

Comment: --title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' 
and      title like '%SUG_' + datename(year, getdate()) + '%'
or Title like '%SUG_'  +  datename(year, getdate()) -1  + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name
order by li.title ASC tried this giving conversion error

Comment: @deepti . . . Your question is about the current year, not about other years.

Comment: i want combine data of 2 queries which iam not getting